# How to format html written part that comes from a python back end?

Tags: python, html

I have the following Html tag.

```
<p align="center" id="question">FormatHere</p>
```

The world "FormatHere" is replace from a string that came from my back end. I saw that By formatting the string in the back end then the format is not mantained in the front end.

Someone know how I can format a string coming from the backend that will replace the world FormatHere?
With specific format I meant that for example I can go head when-ever I want

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to return your string from backend as same name you use in frontend.

example:

```
return template("index.html", context={"string": "FormatHere"})
```

**then**:

```
<p align="center" id="question">{{string}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take values from your Django `.render()` or python `.template()` like so:

```
<p align="center" id="question">{{ object.field }}</p>
```

It depends on the object you are passing, of course. You can execute basic python by using `{{ }}` inside your HTML. Infact, if you have an array of JSONs, you can do a `foreach` and print multiple `<td>` inside a table.

Comment: Yes indeed my question is in json array

Comment: in that case, you have to use indexes, like object.0 (and eventually get the field if it has one)